# How to convert in object raw data received in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, variables, object

Can somebody tell me how to convert in object this raw data received from websocket message:
i am working with angular and ionic.

```
    var data = message.payload;
    console.log(data);
```

in console i get this result for data variable:

```
    {"Time":"2017-08-06T00:54:46", "AM2301":{"Temperature":28.6, 
    "Humidity":50.1}, "TempUnit":"C"}
```

i need to get it as an object, specifically i need to get the "Temperature" value,

thanks for your help.

Comment: `data.AM2301.Temperature` should give you 28.6

Comment: but you should check the API documentation in case AM2301 or the response may differ.

Comment: I receive an error message: "Property "AM2301' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: sounds like you need to parse the data first. var data = JSON.parse(message.payload); // then access the property like sheplu said

Comment: Thankyou, issue solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using :
            `data ['AM2301']['Temperature']`

This will return : 28.6